# pyspark dataframe: how to add a column to auto generate random integer, databricks

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, databricks

There is an existing dataframe, How to add a column called "rating", to pop up integer between 4-9 (4,5,6,7,8,9）randomly?

df:

| Customer | Name |
| --- | --- |
| A | xyz |
| B | opq |
| C | mns |

I need to have such a table, with random value between 4 and 9 added

| Customer | Name | rating |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | xyz | 8 |
| B | opq | 5 |
| C | mns | 7 |

How to write the scripts?
Thank you.

Comment: What you have tried so far? Also, check how to create [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 2):

with pyspark use this 'pyspark.sql.functions.rand' internal function
and using withColumn you can add a new column with random variables.

```
df.withColumn('rating', rand(seed=42) * 10)
```

and for complex assignment use UDF function. Document links below

https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.1/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.sql.functions.rand.html

https://sparkbyexamples.com/pyspark/pyspark-udf-user-defined-function/

Comment: How to make sure it's always integer between 4-9? Thanks.

Comment: df1 = df.withColumn('rand', round(rand()*5).cast("int")+4)